# Convert ppt to jpg

Tags: shell, microsoft-powerpoint, imagemagick, libreoffice

I am using an Ubuntu system. I want to convert ppt or pptx to jpg using terminal commands.

I have libreOffice and ImageMagick installed in my system. I am successfully converting pdf to jpgs using the following command in the terminal -

convert xxx.pdf somefile.jpg

But when i give the first parameter as a ppt it throws off the following error -

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `xxx.ppt' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/533.
convert: missing an image filename`somefile.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2940.

Please help.

Comment: Have you wondered if ppt listed as recognized format for ImageMagick?

Comment: Yeah ur right. Found out that ImageMagick doesn't recognise ppt but can you tell me how can i do the conversion.

Comment: No idea; ask on [su]

Comment: [How to convert pptx files to jpg or png (for each slide) on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21528510/6521116)

Answer (score 2):

In this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/11134/5014) to a related question it's explained that one way to transform from `ppt` to `pdf` from the command line is through [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/).

Hence, to convert from `ppt` to `jpg` you could use something like this:

```
unoconv <filename>.ppt <filename>.pdf
convert <filename>.pdf <filename>.jpg
```

where  is the name of the file you want to convert without the extension.

Comment: this works but the quality of the jpg is bad. Do u know how can i get better quality?

Comment: got it by using the density parameter. Thanks for the help